# MongoDB collection.aggregate usage to retrieve a count

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use the aggregate method within MongoDB from a tiny nodeJS app.  My goal is to simply get a count of how many times a particular key has a value.  I don't care what the value is.  I just want a count per value for that key.

Here is what I've tried:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/implant_history_audit_PROD';

// write to our mongo database
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
    const db = client.db("implant_history_audit_PROD");
    db.collection("implants").aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$person_id",
                count: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        }
    ], (err, result) => {
        result.toArray().then(res => console.log(res), err => console.log(err));
        // fs.writeFileSync("patient_counts.txt", JSON.stringify(result));
    });
    client.close();
});
```

This returns the following: `[ { _id: null, count: 58059 } ]`

Here is what the schema looks like for each document:

```
{
  "IMPLANT_HISTORY_ID":0.000000,
  "IMPLANT_ITEM_ID":0.000000,
  "IMPLANT_ITEM_FT":"Some history free text",
  "IMPLANT_TYPE_CD":0.000000,
  "BIOLOGICAL_IMP_SRC_CD":0.000000,
  "NON_BIOLOGICAL_IMP_TYPE_CD":0.000000,
  "BODY_SITE_CD":0.000000,
  "COMMENTS":"This is a comment",
  "PERSON_ID":123456.000000,
  "ENCNTR_ID":0.000000,
  "EXPIRATION_DT_TM":"\/Date(0000-00-00T00:00:00.000+00:00)\/",
  "EXPLANT_DT_TM":"\/Date(0000-00-00T00:00:00.000+00:00)\/",
  "EXPLANT_DT_TM_PREC_FLAG":0,
  "EXPLANT_REASON_CD":0.000000,
  "IMPLANTED_FACILITY_CD":0.000000,
  "IMPLANTED_FACILITY_FT":"",
  "IMPLANTED_PRSNL_ID":0.000000,
  "IMPLANTED_PRSNL_FT":"",
  "IMPLANTED_DT_TM":"\/Date(1901-01-01T00:00:00.000-04:00)\/",
  "IMPLANTED_DT_TM_PREC_FLAG":3,
  "LOT_NUMBER_TXT":"",
  "MR_CLASSIFICATION_CD":0.000000,
  "PARENT_ENTITY_ID":0.000000,
  "PARENT_ENTITY_NAME":"",
  "PROCEDURE_CD":0.000000,
  "PROCEDURE_NOMEN_ID":0.000000,
  "PROCEDURE_FT":"",
  "IMPLANTED_QUANTITY":1,
  "SERIAL_NUMBER_TXT":"",
  "UDI_TXT":"",
  "DONOR_NUMBER_TXT":"",
  "MANUFACTURED_DT_TM":"\/Date(0000-00-00T00:00:00.000+00:00)\/",
  "MANUFACTURER_CD":0.000000,
  "MANUFACTURER_FT":"",
  "MANUFACTURER_MODEL_NBR_TXT":"",
  "ACTIVE_IND":1,
  "SURG_CASE_PROC_ID":0.000000,
  "DEVICE_IDENTIFIER_TXT":""
 }
```

I am confused because each document has a "person_id" key. Thanks for your insights.

**EDIT:**
I will also mention that the keys in the document are in uppercase.  However, using "$PERSON_ID" causes the script to fail.  The error I get from this is:

> { MongoNetworkError: connection destroyed, not possible to instantiate cursor
>      at nextFunction (C:\Users\cgoepfrich2\Documents\projects\implant migration\PROD\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:707:9)
>      at AggregationCursor.Cursor.next (C:\Users\cgoepfrich2\Documents\projects\implant migration\PROD\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:814:3)
>      at AggregationCursor.Cursor._next (C:\Users\cgoepfrich2\Documents\projects\implant migration\PROD\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:201:36)
>      at fetchDocs (C:\Users\cgoepfrich2\Documents\projects\implant migration\PROD\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:950:10)
>      at C:\Users\cgoepfrich2\Documents\projects\implant migration\PROD\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:976:7
>      at handleCallback (C:\Users\cgoepfrich2\Documents\projects\implant migration\PROD\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:199:5)
>      at nextFunction (C:\Users\cgoepfrich2\Documents\projects\implant migration\PROD\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:804:5)
>      at C:\Users\cgoepfrich2\Documents\projects\implant migration\PROD\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:686:7
>      at queryCallback (C:\Users\cgoepfrich2\Documents\projects\implant migration\PROD\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:263:16)
>      at C:\Users\cgoepfrich2\Documents\projects\implant migration\PROD\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:541:18
>    name: 'MongoNetworkError',
>    message: 'connection destroyed, not possible to instantiate cursor' }

Comment: I have updated the OP with the requested information.  I wasn't sure how best to format the error so I just did a blockquote.

Comment: You're calling `client.close()` before your async aggregate query has finished.

Comment: `"$PERSON_ID"` is correct. Move the `client.close()` to be **inside** the result callback

Comment: Ah, a silly mistake that was.  Thanks everyone!